# python pandas how to merge/join two tables based on substring?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dataframes, and the column names for both are:

```
table 1 columns:
[ShipNumber, TrackNumber, Comment, ShipDate, Quantity, Weight]
table 2 columns:
[ShipNumber, TrackNumber, AmountReceived]
```

I want to merge the two tables when either 'ShipNumber' or 'TrackNumber' from table 2 can be found in 'Comment' from table 1.

Also, I'll explain why

```
merged = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',left_on='Comment',right_on='ShipNumber')
```

does not work in this case.

"Comment" column is a block of texts that can contain anything, so I cannot do an exact match like tab2.ShipNumber == tab1.Comment, because tab2.ShipNumber or tab2.TrackNumber can be found as a substring in tab1.Comment.

The desired output table should have all the unique columns from two tables:

```
output table column names:
[ShipNumber, TrackNumber, Comment, ShipDate, Quantity, Weight, AmountReceived]
```

I hope my question makes sense... 
Any help is really really appreciated!

**note**

The ultimate goal is **to merge two sets with (shipnumber==shipnumber |tracknumber == tracknumber | shipnumber in comments | tracknumber in comments)**, but I've created two subsets for the first two conditions, and now I'm working on the 3rd and 4th conditions.

Comment: Can you create a new column `'ExtractedNum'` using a regular expression on the `'Comment'` column to match something that looks like ShipNumber or TrackNumber? Then you can merge on the new ExtractedNum column. Or is it possible for there to be more than 1 number in the comment?

Comment: the ShipNumber and TrackNumber may not stay in same format.... (few exceptions exists and dont want to exclude those). so thats why i want to just match with the source (table 2). and the 'comment' is a blob of texts can be of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on some made up data.  Ignore the complete nonsense I've put in the dataframes, I was just typing in random stuff to get a sample df to play with.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

x = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Chicago','Houston','Los Angeles','Boston','NYC','blah'],
                  'Comments': ['chicago is winter','la is summer','boston is winter','dallas is spring','NYC is spring','seattle foo'],
                  'Dir':      ['N','S','E','W','S','E']})

y = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['Miami','Dallas'],
                  'Season':   ['Spring','Fall']})


def findval(row):
    comment, location, season = map(lambda x: str(x).lower(),row)
    return location in comment or season in comment

merged = pd.concat([x,y])

merged['Helper'] = merged[['Comments','Location','Season']].apply(findval,axis=1)
print(merged)
filtered = merged[merged['Helper'] == True]
print(filtered)
```

Rather than joining, you can conatenate the dataframes, and then create a helper to see if the string of one column is found in another.  Once you have that helper column, just filter out the True's.

Comment: this does not work; sorry for not making my question clear. i'll edit my question now.

Comment: basically, the "comment" is a long string, but shipnumber could be a substring included in the "comment" string. hence cannot use merge function like this.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to join on a function call - perhaps concatenating the df's together, and then making a helper column which does a `re.search` or  simple `trackingnum in Comment or shipnumber in comment`.  After that, you can just filter the df as normally for that helper column being true.

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like

```
Count = 0
def MergeFunction(rowElement):
    global Count
    df2_row = df2.iloc[[Count]]
    if(df2_row['ShipNumber'] in rowElement['Comments'] or df2_row['TrackNumber'] 
       in rowElement['Comments']
    rowElement['Amount'] = df2_row['Amount']
    Count+=1
    return rowElement

df1['Amount'] = sparseArray #Fill with zeros
new_df = df1.apply(MergeFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could index the comments field using a library like [Whoosh](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) and then do a text search for each shipment number that you want to search by.